# Git how to diff against remote svn repo

Tags: git, svn

Is it possible to diff a local git repository against a remote and external svn repository?

So I have a local git repository and I want to see the differences between it and a 3rd party repository located externally and accessible via http.

Its not feesable to download this external repository since i want to wrap this in a script that can be called on demand and quickly determine any differences.

Answer (score 0):

1. Checkout project from the svn repo in a folder.
2. Copy `.git` folder into the svn working copy.
3. `git diff`.

So, you will have a working copy for both systems in one place.

Maybe you need to add `.svn` into ignore list of the git.